# Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta})$ for irrational $\theta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

What is the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta})$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is irrational?

It seems that this basis depends on the value of $\theta$

Comment: You mean $e^{i \pi \theta}$ where $\theta$ is irrational? In this case, $e^{i \pi \theta}$ is transcendental, so this field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. You can write down an explicit basis for $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ using partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, without $\pi$, then what happens?  I just mean $e^{i\theta}$, and for this case if $\theta = \pi$ or some integers of $\pi$ it can be algebraic

Comment: Without the $\pi$ I don't know why you require that $\theta$ be irrational. Nothing particularly special happens to $e^{i \theta}$ when $\theta$ is rational.

Comment: To expand a bit on @QiaochuYuan comment, if you want to examine simply $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is irrational, then either $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ or it is not. If it is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then you will obtain a Cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field ; bases for these extensions are easily described. Otherwise, $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, in which case the extension is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, as he pointed out.